# Creating a pair with two generic types on Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following piece of code

```
type Pair<A,B> = { fst: A, snd: B }

function pair<A,B>(a:A) {

  return function (b:B):Pair<A,B> {

    return {
      fst: a,
      snd: b
    }

  }

}

const z = pair(2)("aaa")
```

the type of `z` is `Pair<number,unknown>`. Is there a way to allow TypeScript to infer the type of `B` in `z`?
Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgSwE4B4CCAaAQgPigXigG8oAzAZ2AC4pMpyA7AExqygF8AoT0gVwYDGwBAHsGUMIlSZcACjhU0ASmLcoUJBGC8k4voOFiosgEZUsSqvGTpseImvUatO8Q6dOK1KHAycP6owsUCb%20TlxhERFQAmKUUABeBBJSsgBMSrIARHC5WUrcQA) with the piece above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function type parameters should be on the function where they are inferred. Move `B` to the inner function and it works as expected

```
type Pair<A,B> = { fst: A, snd: B }

function pair<A>(a:A) {

  return function <B>(b:B):Pair<A,B> {

    return {
      fst: a,
      snd: b
    }

  }

}

 const z = pair(2)("aaa")
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgSwE4B4CCAaAQgPigXigG8oAzAZ2AC4pMpyA7AExqygF8AoT0gVwYDGwBAHsGUMIlRocACjhU0ASmLcoUJBGC8k4voOFioKXLIBGVLEqrxk6bHiJr1GrTvFOXLitShwMnF7qjCxQZoEuXBFRUVACYpRQAF4EElKyAExKsgBEcPk5StxAA)